# How to construct a table of frequency counts of items in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, word-frequency, frequency-distribution

Say I have the following data in a csv file, `example.csv`:

```
Word    Score
Dog     1
Bird    2
Cat     3
Dog     2
Dog     3
Dog     1
Bird    3
Cat     1
Bird    1
Cat     3
```

I want to count the frequency of each word for each score. The expected output is the following:

```
        1   2   3
Dog     2   1   1
Bird    0   1   1
Cat     1   0   2
```

My code to do this is as follows:

import pandas as pd

```
x1 = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\example.csv')

def getUniqueWords(allWords) :
    uniqueWords = [] 
    for i in allWords:
        if not i in uniqueWords:
            uniqueWords.append(i)
    return uniqueWords

unique_words = getUniqueWords(x1['Word'])
unique_scores = getUniqueWords(x1['Score'])

scores_matrix = [[0 for x in range(len(unique_words))] for x in range(len(unique_scores)+1)]   
# The '+1' is because Python indexing starts from 0; so if a score of 0 is present in the data, the 0 index will be used for that. 

for i in range(len(unique_words)):
    temp = x1[x1['Word']==unique_words[i]]
    for j, word in temp.iterrows():
        scores_matrix[i][j] += 1  # Supposed to store the count for word i with score j
```

But this gives the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-141ab9cd7847> in <module>()
     19     temp = x1[x1['Word']==unique_words[i]]
     20     for j, word in temp.iterrows():
---> 21         scores_matrix[i][j] += 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Also, even if I could fix this error, the `scores_matrix` would not show the headers (`Dog`, `Bird`, `Cat` as row indices, and `1`, `2`, `3` as column indices). I would want to be able to access the count for each word with each score - something to this effect:

```
scores_matrix['Dog'][1]
>>> 2

scores_matrix['Cat'][2]
>>> 0
```

So, how would I solve/fix both these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with sort=False and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) or [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Word', sort=False)['Score'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Word','Score'], sort=False).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print (df1)
Score  1  2  3
Word          
Dog    2  1  1
Bird   1  1  1
Cat    1  0  2
```

If order is not important use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Word'], df['Score'])
print (df1)
Score  1  2  3
Word          
Bird   1  1  1
Cat    1  0  2
Dog    2  1  1
```

Last select by labels with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc['Cat', 2])
0
```

Comment: Ok, that works. I didn't know about these at all! By the way, how do I access the count for a specific score for a specific word? Something to the effect of, `df['Dog']['1']` should return `2`, `df['Cat']['2']` should return `0`, etc.